# An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in the user code

Tags: c#

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
        {
            string kundeID = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            if (kundeID != null)
            {

                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                int totalsum = Convert.ToInt32(ddlAmount.SelectedValue);



                Handlevogn handlevogn = new Handlevogn
                {
                    TotalSum = totalsum,
                    KundeID = short.Parse(kundeID),
                    Dato = DateTime.Now,
                    ErIHandlevogn = true,
                    ProduktID = id
                };

                HandlevognModell model = new HandlevognModell();
                lblResult.Text = model.InsertHandlevogn(handlevogn);
            }
            else
            {
                lblResult.Text = "Please log in to order items";
            }
```

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   but was not handled in user code

[Here is the error i get when I try to add items to my shoppingcart in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erfte.png)

[Model.cs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9WVB.png)

Comment: Please specify an explaination of where exactly this error is occuring. Switch your parsings to TryParse so you wont get this exception and will know whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a toString call

```
KundeID = short.Parse(kundeID.ToString());
```

So it basically becomes like

```
Handlevogn handlevogn = new Handlevogn
            {
                TotalSum = totalsum,
                KundeID = short.Parse(kundeID.toString()),
                Dato = DateTime.Now,
                ErIHandlevogn = true,
                ProduktID = id
            };
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Still getting the exact same error.. I uploaded another picture if it's any more helpful.

Comment: Can you please debug your code and tell me what is the value of kundleID you are getting?

Comment: kundeID should have the value 46598e0b-0af7-4c26-a980-144d58d19325 since I am logged into a user with this ID, but I'm not sure if this is what you're asking?

Comment: How can you parse 46598e0b-0af7-4c26-a980-144d58d19325 to short, obviously it will throw exception. why do you want to parse this value to shot, any specific reason?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but in the model.cs file, which you can see in the post now, was automatically set to short. Any way I can convert this to a string now? In my db this is set to nvarchar{255}

Comment: Yes, it should be string only.